# How to trim a value in php?

Tags: php, trim, texttrimming

I'm trying to take a value from some variable which looks like this:

```
$ a= '[custom:data-rekrutacji]';
```

using **[custom:data-rekrutacji]** token which I've already defined which should contain the value: **2015-08-11 13:00:00**, but if I check it using `var_dump()` as below:

```
var_dump($a);
```

I'm getting something like this:

```
string(24) "
2015-08-11 13:00:00

"
```

However I would like to have only this (as below) so I can use function `strtotime($a)`:

```
2015-08-11 13:00:00
```

Is it possible to trim this?

I've tried in this way, but without success:

```
$a= '[custom:data-rekrutacji]';
trim($a);
echo strtotime($a);
```

Comment: You'll have to figure out *where* the `[placeholder]` gets swapped for a datetime string. That's also where the extraneous linebreaks originate. And where they should be trimmed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried saving the change:

$a = trim($a);

```
$a= '[custom:data-rekrutacji]';
$a = trim($a);
echo strtotime($a);
```

**EDIT:**

If your variable has the correct values it should output correctly.

```
$a= "    2015-08-11 13:00:00    ";
$a = trim($a);
echo "Trimmed: [".$a."]\n";
echo strtotime($a);
```

Code between the [ ] shows it was trimmed correctly, the next one should return the time in an int.

This is the result I get:

```
Trimmed: [2015-08-11 13:00:00]
1439290800
```

Comment: it returns nothing after: echo strtotime($a);

Comment: Make sure the initial $a contains the data you want.

I'll update the example using the values you had.

Answer (score 0):

When using [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) function, remember it returns a string, not changing the existing one. So to make it work, you should do:

```
$a = trim($a);
```

instead of just:

```
trim($a);
```

> As this function **returns** a string with whitespace stripped from the beginning and end of *str*.